# velocity verlet algorithm c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I try to get the position and velocity of a car going down a hill using verlet algorithm. However I keep getting

> error: invalid operands of types 'double' and 'double [(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)n) + -1)) + 1)]' to binary 'operator*'|

Why is this happening?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

int n=100;
int m=100;
double const gx=0;
double const gy=-9.8;

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int i;
    double t[n], x[n], y[n], r[n], vx[n], vy[n], gx[n], gy[n];
    double h = 2.0/(n-1), h2=h*h/2, r2, r3;
    //double t[0]=0,x[0]=0,y[0]=20;
    //double r[0]=x[0],vx[0]=0,vy[0]=0;
    double ke[n], mass=1500;
    t[0]=0;
    x[0]=0;
    y[0]=20;
    r[0]=x[0];
    vx[0]=0;
    vy[0]=0;
    ke[0]=0;

    for(i=0; i<n-1; i++){
        t1=t[0]+h;
        x[i+1]=x[i]+h*vx[i]+h2*gx;
        y[i+1]=y[i]+h*vy[i]+h2*gy;
        r2=x[i+1]*x[i+1]+y[i+1]*y[i+1];
        r[i+1] = sqrt(r2);
        r3=r2*r[i+1];
        vx[i]=vx[i]+h*gx/2;
        vy[i]=vy[i]+h*gy/2;

        cout << t[i+1] << x[i+1] << y[i+1] << r[i+1] << vx[i] << vy[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using raw arrays instead of `std::vector<double>`?

Comment: `gx` is an array type, not a `double`, hence the error.

Comment: thank you very much. i fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
... h2*gx;
```

`h2` is a `double`. `gx` is an array. You can't, obviously, multiply a single `double` value by an array. That's an error, and that's exactly what the compiler's error message says.

This is not the only line with this error.

You probably meant to write `gx[i]` here, and `gy[i]` on the next line.

Comment: Actually he has another gx defined as double, so it must be a typo

Comment: It is true that C++ doesn't allow multiplying a double by an array - but there is nothing particularly *obvious* about that.  I can perfectly well imagine a language where double * array yielded an array.